# Does coriander juice help in chelation and excretion of toxic metals?

Tags: toxicology

Many articles claim that [coriander](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriander) juice (a.k.a. cilantro) has [chelation properties](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3654245/) and help in excrement of toxic metals.

For example: [Raw Food Hypocrite](http://rawfoodhypocrite.com/tag/dr-yoshiaki-omura/):

> A recent study by Dr. Yoshiaki Omura from the Heart Disease Research Foundation, New York,  has discovered that the herb cilantro will detoxify mercury from neural tissue*., is used to help stimulate the appetite and relieves minor digestive irritation.

Is this scientifically validated?

Answer (score 2):

There is no limited evidence of it working, and some evidence that it doesn't work.

I didn't have to go far. You defined "chelation properties" with a link to:

- Margaret E. Sears, [*Chelation: Harnessing and Enhancing Heavy Metal Detoxification—A Review*](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3654245/), Scientific World Journal. 2013; 2013: 219840. doi:  10.1155/2013/219840

It is a review of the evidence. It covers cilantro:

> (iv) Cilantro (leaves of *Coriandrum sativum*), a popular culinary and medicinal herb, gained attention when a soup was reported to enhance mercury excretion following dental amalgam removal and remains popular despite limited evidence [46]. In animals, it decreased lead absorption into bone and inhibition of the delta-aminolevulinic acid dehydratase (ALAD) enzyme [47]. Less encouragingly, in a recent trial in 3- to 7-year old children exposed to lead, a cilantro extract was as effective as placebo in increasing renal excretion (improvements across treatment and placebo groups were ascribed to improved diet during the intervention) [48].